# What does it mean by "has to say"?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to add more about my question. Rob and Finn were the hosts at the learning English program. They wanted to listen to an expert about their topic. So, they said "Let's listen to what the expert has to say". In this context, what they mean by "has to say"?

plus, thank you for sharing knowledge about usage of "say"

---

I listened to a certain English learning audioclip. In the program, they said "He has to say about some subject". I could infer the meaning, but I would like to know the exact meaning of the expression. Would you guys please give me a help with that?

Comment: I don't think that this could have been the entire sentence. Perhaps: "We want to hear what he has to say about XXX" or "I have to say I am very disappointed" could you give a little more context?

Comment: "say" is always with a direct object, e.g. "Say hi!" or "Say it!" or "What did he say?". So, "Here's what **he has to say about X**." is fine. Or "He has to say **something** about X." is also fine.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. "has to say" in this context means "would like to say" or "must say" / "really can't resist saying".

Comment: @djna So basically you mean that, we can't say "Say something!", but we should always phrase it "Say about something!"? I don't agree.

Comment: @technophyle The question has been edited since I gave my comment. The original sentence in question was "He has to say about some subject."  This is clearly not a complete sentence. I was giving two examples of how it might be part of a larger, more complete sentence. I agree with you that "Say something!" is perfectly fine, and I did not intend to imply otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hear (or, *see*, for some weird reason) what someone "has to say", means to hold off on a conclusion until factoring in the insight or opinion of that person. It infers that said person's input is important to the subject.